# encodeData writeToFile EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, unrecognized-selector

I am trying to save my game data. I began with this tutorial from Ray: [How to Save your Game’s Data: Part 1/2](http://www.raywenderlich.com/63235/how-to-save-your-game-data-tutorial-part-1-of-2)

Everything works fine except `-(void)save;`

```
-(void)save
{
    NSData* encodedData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject: self];
    [encodedData writeToFile:[RWGameData filePath] atomically:YES];
}
```

When I called this method I get this;

```
 -[__NSCFArray getFileSystemRepresentation:maxLength:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1663dcc0
2014-07-14 18:42:15.029 App[3629:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray getFileSystemRepresentation:maxLength:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1663dcc0'
```

Or this:
   **exc_bad_access code=1 address=0xc** or  **exc_bad_access code=1 address=0x7000000c** or  **exc_bad_access code=1 address=0x1000000c**
     on this line:

```
 [encodedData writeToFile:[RWGameData filePath] atomically:YES];
```

How can I fix this? Source code from tutorial works fine. But in my game its crashed.

**UPDATE:**

In Ray's source code **Objective C ARC: YES**. But then I use ARC, it gives me tons of errors.

**EDIT:** I changed code a little bit and go to a second part of a tutorial. Save/Load work correctly first run, but on second run it load correctly only once and when I trying to change score values I have **exc_bad_access**.

```
  +(instancetype)loadInstance
  { 
     pathString = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, 
    NSUserDomainMask, YES) firstObject] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"gamedata"];

NSData* decodedData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile: pathString];
if (decodedData) {
    //1
    NSString* checksumOfSavedFile = [KeychainWrapper computeSHA256DigestForData: decodedData];

    //2
    NSString* checksumInKeychain = [KeychainWrapper keychainStringFromMatchingIdentifier:   SSGameDataChecksumKey];

    //3
    if ([checksumOfSavedFile isEqualToString: checksumInKeychain]) {
        RWGameData* gameData = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:decodedData];
        return gameData;
    }
    //4
 }

 return [[RWGameData alloc] init];
}

  -(void)save
{
   pathString = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, 
 NSUserDomainMask,  YES) firstObject] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"gamedata"];

NSData* encodedData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject: self];
[encodedData writeToFile:pathString atomically:YES];

NSString* checksum = [KeychainWrapper computeSHA256DigestForData: encodedData];
if ([KeychainWrapper keychainStringFromMatchingIdentifier: SSGameDataChecksumKey]) {
    [KeychainWrapper updateKeychainValue:checksum forIdentifier:SSGameDataChecksumKey];
} else {
    [KeychainWrapper createKeychainValue:checksum forIdentifier:SSGameDataChecksumKey];
}

if([NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore defaultStore]) {
    [self updateiCloud];
}
}
```

**EXC_BAD_ACCSES on this line in my gamelayer after updated score:**

```
 [RWGameData sharedGameData].score += 1;
```

But if I call this line from init method - its working.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `+[RWGameData filePath]` method implementation. It appears to be actually returning an array, not a string as expected.

You can see this from the "unrecognized selector" message, thrown by `NSCFArray` (which is an internal implementation of an `NSArray`). That array is complaining that someone is trying to access a method on it that only exists on strings. Since you're not doing that yourself directly, the `-writeToFile:...` method must be doing that on the result of `-filePath` on `RWGameData`.

Comment: You are right. [RWGameData filePath] from `-writeToFile` return some random things like images name, CCFrameSprites, arrays or whatever. How can I fix this?

Comment: You should post that method in the question. How closely does it match the implementation given in the tutorial link you posted?